# How to create pdf like a example using fpdf

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

This is my PDF code below:

```
$this->SetFillColor(0);
$this->SetTextColor(255,255,255);
$this->Cell(90,10,$airline_name,'LRBT',0,'L',true);

$this->Cell('10',10,'','',0,'L',false);

$this->SetFillColor(255,255,255);
$this->SetTextColor(0);
$this->SetFont('Times','',10);

$this->MultiCell(90,5,$com_info,1,'L',false);

$this->Ln(0);

$this->SetY(23);
$this->Cell(30,10,"MAWB",'LTB',0,'L',false);
$this->Cell(60,10,$mawb,'TRB',0,'L',false);
$this->Cell(10,10,'','',0,'L',false);

$this->Cell(45,20,'This Pieces No.\n$pn','LR',0,'L',false);
$this->Cell(45,20,'Total Pieces\n$pn','R',0,'L',false);
$this->ln(0);

$this->SetY(36);
$this->Cell(30,10,"Booking_ref",'LTB',0,'L',false);
$this->Cell(60,10,$booking_ref,'TRB',0,'L',false);
$this->Cell(10,10,'','',0,'L',false);

$this->Cell(25,20,'HAWB','LTR',0,'L',false);
$this->Cell(65,20,$quotation_no,'TR',0,'L',false);
```

According to above code, the PDF is as shown below:
**pdf image No.01**
[image]

Basically, I want to do display it as shown here:
**pdf image No.02**
[image]

In the PDF, the data will come from the database.

I would like to display like **pdf image No.02** But i have done like **pdf image No.01**.

How to get the pdf image like **pdf image No.02**.

How can I solve it? Please help.

Comment: Everything seems fine! What is the problem?

Comment: Please see attentively , Below Pdf image is not same over it. How to take two table in same page. which i will give padding and margin like below pdf image. Basically i want to do exact like below pdf image.

Comment: So you have to set the exactly positions!

Comment: You can follow this example: http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script14.php

Comment: fpdf has pretty good samples... it takes a bit to get used to formatting, but with trial and error on positioning, you should have no problem doing what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert Rozas. But your script link is fine but. Please Attentively pdf image . I want to do like below full pdf image. My Above pdf image is not same . So your script in not like my last pdf image. Please Check and i hope good solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot powtac. How can i give exact position which will be my last pdf image. Please see nicely row border is not same line. So How can i best solution. Please any suggestion.

Comment: Thanks a lot mjayt. How to give position rightly? Which will be show like my last pdf image.

Comment: Please All, I have some changed my problem. Please See again . Please any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Not overly familiar with fPDF. It looks OK for quick, simple stuff.
Have you tried using R&OS ezPDF Creator instead - not sure what state of development/maintenance it's in these days but I think it may give you more detailed control for the kind of output you want.
I've used it for years for bespoke PDF output from PHP.
Just checked and it looks like it's still being maintained - see:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdf-php/

Cheers,
Arthur

Answer (score 1):

I have tried fpdf and a few other libraries for a big job i have done a couple of years back. You might want to look at dompdf, the library takes html and converts it into pdf flawlessly (after a couple of tries to get it right, but still) - only thing is, read the docs - images (like your barcode there) must be linked with server path, i.e. /path/to/image/image.jpg

Comment: generating html and convert it to a pdf is a last-resort workaround.

Comment: snapping a quick html for your desired layout is always easier, faster, and more convenient than 1000 lines of $this->SetXXXColor(); and $this->Cell(); and similar

Comment: agree, it's faster – but way less failprove to my experience. And the size of the PDF is most of the time relevantly bigger.

Comment: the size (file size) depends on more than one factor. plus, you got a bit of extra flexibility with html converted pdf's. That's what i used and it still works today, 5 years from when i implemented it...

Answer (score 1):

Basically it looks ok. Its just a bunch of little things to adapt. e.g. setting the font to bold is done via `$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',14);` before the output statement and setting it back to `$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',14);` afterwards. See [fpdf documentation](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/setfont.htm) for details.